# Binomial Distribution ( random variables problem)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Im having a problem with understanding where to start solving the following problem :
\begin{align}
X & \sim \operatorname{Bin}(10,0.41) \\
(Y\mid X=x) & \sim \operatorname{Bin}(x+1,\,0.12) \\
P(X=0,Y=0) & = \text{?}
\end{align}

I have only just been introduced to random variables, i started by finding the probability of $X=0$ using the binomial distribution formula, but i cant figure out what to do with the rest. Any tips or explanations are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=0\ \&\ Y=0) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(X=0)\cdot\Pr(Y=0\mid X=0) \\[10pt]
= {} & \binom{10} 0 0.41^0 (1-0.41)^{10-0} \cdot \binom{0+1} 0 0.12^0 (1-0.12)^{(0+1)-0} = \cdots\cdots 
\end{align}
Maybe the second line above is central to what you need.

Comment: firstly thanks, 1 question: can we assume that the variables are independant ( if not we cant multiply the pr right?)

Comment: They're not independent because you said $(Y\mid X=x) \sim \operatorname{Bin}(x+1,\,0.12). \qquad$